# Mysql diversified results

Tags: mysql

I got table in db in following way:

```
id   Name    Type
1.   Aero.      Product
2.   Ddd.       Product
3.   Sass.      Image
4.   Rrrrr.       Image
```

This is just to understand and actual table in much bigger scale.
So the question is how to get diversfied results so the product type wont be like product,product, image, image

If i will do `select * from table where 1 order by ‘id’
Results having grouped “type”`
I want have results like

```
1 blabla product
3 blabla image
2 blabla product
4 blabla image
```

So the records with same type will be spreaded over results and 
As much as possible wont stay together

Comment: Just shuffle them in application language.

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND()` will shuffle the order.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested its better if you do this type of sorting in your application code, In Mysql you can do this by using user defined variables.

First break your data according to your types, get data for products and assign a row number and do the same with second data set for type image and then merge these sets using union operation and then sort them by row number

```
select *
from(
  select d1.*, @row1:= @row1 + 1 as row
  from demo d1,
  (select @row1:=0) t1
  where `Type` = 'Product'
  union all
  select d2.*, @row2:= @row2 + 1 as row
  from demo d2,
  (select @row2:=0) t2
  where `Type` = 'Image'
) t
order by t.row, t.Type desc
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d97234/9)

Comment: "better if you do this type of sorting in your application code" - Why?

Comment: It can be too expensive operation on DB side

Comment: No - its much more expensive to do this in your application. Databases are designed for this kind of thing. Where it does make sense is when you are Facebook or Google - it's a lot cheaper (even though they are less efficient at sorting) to add application nodes than to add database nodes. Do you believe Boris is the chief architect at an institution handing over a million requests a minute? And in your answer, having stated it should be in the application code, you implement the logic in the database?